# Laravel api route with postman not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, postman

I started a new project on Laravel 5.3 with xampp on Windows, I instaled the cors package(https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) to do request in other domains in the future too.

But on localhost using postman The routes are not working I have this on /routes/api.php:

```
Route::get('/hello', 'AppController@hello');
```

On controller:

```
public function hello()
    {
        return "hello!";
    }
```

on postman:

http://localhost/myproject/api/hello

Responds "object not found error 404", I tried with http://localhost:80/myproject/api/hello and same response.

When I put this http://localhost/myproject/public/api/hello I get the response: "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:"

So I don't get it, is this a laravel 5.3 bug or something? This is my php artisan route list:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name     | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |          | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/hello              |          | App\Http\Controllers\AppController@hello                               | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |          | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   |          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                  |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
```

Comment: Your code is correct. It seems like you are missing some configuration for that CORS package. This will definitely work without that package:
http://localhost/myproject/public/api/hello

Comment: @ParthVora You are right I found that this package in Laravel 5.3 is missing
 'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
     \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
] on the Kernel.php file

Comment: Did you fix this issue already? apply the `cors` middleware to your route and you should be okay. otherwise, check that your route is indeed prefix with `api` I mean are you sure that it is `api/some/link` and not `some/link` ?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi actually the request now is working with my last comment and te call route is: http://localhost/myproject/public/api/hello

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're getting this error due to a missing url segment: /public
The URL should be: /public/api/hello

Answer (score 0):

In the url section remove the `myproject` section.